# Changing coordinate system with non standard definitions

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

The standard coordinate transformation to polar coordinates is
$$
\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\varphi)\\
y=r\sin(\varphi)
\end{cases}
$$
with $r\in[0,\infty), \ \varphi\in[0,2\pi)$

The question is whether I can make the same transformations but with $r\in(-\infty,\infty), \ \varphi\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Will this be valid, if not then why? Cause it looks like it can ease some calculations.

Comment: $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=1\sin(\pi/4)=(-1)(\sin(-\pi/4))$... not sure if this is a problem or not...

Comment: This should work as well (The inverse is well-defined).

Comment: @JpMcCarthy thanks, I see it.I guess that's the point.

Comment: @AlexR Now I guess not. The transformation is no a single-valued one. :(

Comment: @user91450: Yes it is (if you don't count the origin, but there is the same issue with standard definition).

Comment: Remember you have a pair $(x,y)$, so given
$(x,y) = (a, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, $\varphi$ is determined by $a$ as well...